# Problem with vertical text in inner margins

Tags: positioning, margins, book-design, text-decorations, copyright

I'm having troubles in setting the copyright notice and vertical title right, with the following code.  I need to fix two things:

1. The vertical text should stay inside their gray zone (as it is, currently), but the text baseline should be at exactly 0.5in from the paper edge.  Currently, it's too close to the paper edge.
2. I want to completely remove the vertical gray band from the code (since it has an issue with printing).

So how can I fix this code?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\distance}
\setlength{\distance}{0.0in}
\newlength{\rulethickness}
\setlength{\rulethickness}{0.5in}
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{\paperheight}
\newlength{\xoffset}
\newlength{\yoffset}
\setlength{\yoffset}{0pt}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\distance}%
    \else
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\rulethickness-\distance}%
    \fi
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{\yoffset}){%
        \colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[b][\ruleheight][c]{\rulethickness}{%
        \centering
        \ifodd\value{page}%
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{red}{\large{\normalfont\textsc{Copyright notice}}}}%
        \else
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{blue}{\huge{\normalfont\textsc{Some Title}}}}%
        \fi
    }}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\newpage
Another page

\end{document}
```

I must admit that I don't understand clearly how this code is working, especially for the gray band that I'm yet unable to remove (without trivialy changing its color to white).  Preview of what this code is doing, and the issues shown in red:

[image]

Comment: Wat do you mean with the ‘paper edge’, exactly?

Comment: @Bernard, I mean just that: the border of the paper sheet.  Currently, the vertical text baseline is too close to it, and I need it to be aligned with the border of the gray zone (which is at 0.5in of the paper edge). After that, I need to remove completely the gray zone, which is useless.

Comment: The vertical part of the paper sheet border?

Comment: @Bernard, I guess this is obvious:  the left and right parts of the paper!

Comment: You might have wanted the text closer to the top or bottom edge!

Comment: @Bernard, no, I need the text to stay centered (vertically).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: I added an invisible rule with length 2.5em, before  or after the rotated text, depending on the page being even or odd:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\distance}
\setlength{\distance}{0.0in}
\newlength{\rulethickness}
\setlength{\rulethickness}{0.5in}
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{\paperheight}
\newlength{\xoffset}
\newlength{\yoffset}
\setlength{\yoffset}{0pt}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\distance}%
    \else
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\rulethickness-\distance}%
    \fi
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{\yoffset}){%
        \colorbox{lightgray!50}{\parbox[b][\ruleheight][c]{\rulethickness}{%
        \centering
        \ifodd\value{page}%
           \rule{2.5em}{0pt}\rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{red}{\large{\normalfont\textsc{Copyright notice}}}}%
        \else
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{blue}{\huge{\normalfont\textsc{Some Title}}}}\rule{2.5em}{0pt}%
        \fi
    }}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\newpage
Another page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just found that removing \centering and using \flushright inside the \ifodd\value{page} solves the position issue.  But then how to remove the gray band?

Comment: Just remove `\colorbox{lightgray}{`  and one of the final `}`. Keep only the `\parbox`.

Comment: It works.  Is it better/simpler to use \flushright, instead of your \rule{2.5em}{0pt}?

Comment: If it works, yes, it's better. The length of my rule was found by trial and error.

Comment: Hmm, there's a glitch with my solution.  The copyright notice has a vertical offset:  it's slightly lower than what it should (not exactly centered vertically).  Can you see where's the cause?  Your solution doesn't have this vertical glitch.

Comment: Not exactly, and I can't test at the moment (it's getting late here). Of course, you always can add a small spacing to the contents of te rotated box, by trial and error. Could you post a code reproducing your problem? I'll try to look at it tomorrow.

Comment: My solution above is having the vertical offset glitch.  The copyright notice isn't exactly centered, while the title is centered on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution I was looking for.  Can it be improved in some way?  (the preview picture is the same as the one in Bernard's solution, but without the gray band):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\xoffset}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \setlength{\xoffset}{0in}%
    \else
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.5in}%
    \fi
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{0in}){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight][c]{0.5in}{%
        \ifodd\value{page}%
            \flushright
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{red}{\large{\normalfont\textsc{Copyright notice}}}}%
        \else
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{blue}{\huge{\normalfont\textsc{Some Title}}}}%
        \fi
    }}}%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\newpage
Another page

\end{document}
```